# Change config value dynamically in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

how to change Laravel database name in config file dynamically. i know the value for database, after some function is executed in controller. after change config value i can able access the new value from other controllers too.

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

in my app i have 3 databases. every time i create a new database dynamically after deleting previous one. so that time only i have database name with timestamp. in database config i only have empty value for db name.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? What you have tried?

Comment: in my app i have 3 databases. every time i create a new database dynamically after deleting previous one. so that time only i have database name  with timestamp. in database config i only have empty value for db name.